# RegEx No 2 of the "." (dot) characters can ever appear together in a url

Tags: javascript, regex

Need help for url input in javascript, these are my requirements:

```
<br>

- starts with "https://" or "http://"<br>
- no "." after "https://" or "http://"<br>
- ends with ".com"<br>
- no 2 "." characters can appear together<br>
```

This is my expression: `"((^https:\/\/[^.])|(^http:\/\/[^.]))(([\w\d#/:.])*)(\.com)"`

I got the first 3 requirements working but i cant seem to get the last one to work.

Expected pass cases:
http://www.google.com
https://www.facebook.com

Expected fail cases:
http://.ww..google.com
www.google.com
http://www..google.com
https://www.google..com

Comment: How exactly are you creating the RegExp instance?

Comment: `^https?:\/\/(?!.*\.\.)[^.].*\.com$`

Comment: Try it like this `https?://[^.\s]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)*\.com$` https://regex101.com/r/i9Bjx2/1

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
^https?:\/\/[^.\s]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)*\.com$
```

In parts

- `https?:\/\/` Match `http` (optional s) and the `://`
- `[^.\s]+` Match any char except a `.` or whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\.[^.\s]+` Match a `.` and 1+ times any char except a . or whitespace char
- `)*\.com` Close group and match `.com`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/al9LLS/1)

This part `[^.\s]` will match any char except a dot or whitespace char and is a broad match. You could narrow it down to for example `[\w#\/:]`

**Note** that `\w` also matches `\d`